# Return instance of unknown class?

Tags: c#

OK, so, I may be nuts but is it possible to return a value of an unknown type and have it get functions?

Basically a function that looks like...

```
public static ?????? Test(char c)
{
    if(c == char)
        return instance of SOMECLASS
    else
        return instance of SOMEOTHERCLASS
}

// so i could do
Test(new char()).SOMECLASS_METHOD();
Test(new int()).SOMEOTHERCLASS_METHOD();
```

Please & Thanks

EDIT: Just to add, is there a way to also make it appear in intellisense?

Comment: I sense this question comes from a long chain of something else...What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: FYI - Anything you do that makes you not need to know the type (reflection/dynamic/etc) will also make intellisense not work.

Answer (score 4):

You can return `dynamic` (in C# 4 or later), which lets you use dynamic binding.

That will let any method be written, and only fail at *runtime* if the method (or property) doesn't exist on the object.

For example, you can write:

```
class Foo { 
   void Bar() { Console.WriteLine("Foo.Bar"); }
}

class Bar { 
   void Baz() { Console.WriteLine("Bar.Baz"); }
}

public static dynamic Test(char c)
{
   if (c == 'f') return new Foo();
   else return new Bar();
}
```

With that, you could write:

```
Test('f').Bar();
Test('q').Baz();
Test('z').Bar(); // Will raise exception at runtime
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to also make it appear in intellisense?

Comment: @Ber53rker No.  The type is "unknown" until runtime, so there's no intellisense when using `dynamic`.

Comment: I think it bears mentioning that if the OP thinks he needs to use this technique, there is almost certainly something wrong with his design.

Comment: @KirkWoll In very many cases, yes.  Not always - there are occasionally very good reasons to use dynamic, but they're few and far between in C#.

Comment: Right, and hence "almost certainly".  Anyway, your comment has satisfied my pedantry. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static object Test(char c)
{
    if(c == char)
        return instance of SOMECLASS
    else
        return instance of SOMEOTHERCLASS
}

// so i could do
var r = Test(new char());
if (r is SOMECLASS)
   (r as SOMECLASS).SOMECLASS_METHOD();
var rr = Test(new int());
if (rr is SOMEOTHERCLASS)
   (rr as SOMEOTHERCLASS).SOMEOTHERCLASS_METHOD();
```